# How to use ati's fglrx drivers on Fedora 11

Tags: drivers, xorg, fedora-11, fglrx

Has anyone got a clue what is required to make old Fedora 10 ati fglrx drivers from Livna rpm repository on Fedora 11 ?

There was once similar pathway when fedora10 was out but ati didnt support fedoras new kernel and or Xorg version yet so that you could use F9's drivers on F10.

Also, reason why i'm asking this because it seems that *new* ati drivers that where just released has deprecated support for allmost all older non HD cards and if livna/rpmfusion releases the new drivers only, the old ones could still be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here:

http://gofedora.com/archives/2009/08/22/install-ati-catalyst-fglrx-98-drivers-fedora-11/

Allthou im not sure if this works on older cards since presumably support for older cards have been deprecated at some point.

Comment: And note, while this maybe working solutions, it doesnt really help in my case since my card (X800/R420) is deprecated in latest drivers so i guess i need to make my hard dirty and use F10's Xorg and possibly a kernel too in F11 to make things work